# how to compare array from sqlite with contents with json array

Tags: java, android, arrays, sqlite

Hi I´m having a problems with the best strategy to compare an array from an sqlite database and a json array coming from a webservice response . Please tell me the best way to compare this two arrays . Here is my code :

```
public void getAllElements() {
     Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
     try {
        //select all query
        db.open();
        Cursor cc= db.getAllEntries();
        try {
            // looping through all rows and adding to list
            if (cc.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                   map.put("ID",cc.getString(cc.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.ENTRY_ID)));
                } while (cc.moveToNext());
            }
        } finally {
            try { cc.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
        }
    } finally {
         try { db.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
    }
    // return  list 
}

protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // Creating service handler class instance

    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); // Thread
    String uri = "url";

    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
    httpget.setHeader("Cookie", cookie);

    try {
        response = client.execute(httpget);
        // response
        String res = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

        // jarray with the json responde
        jArr = new JSONArray(res);
        System.out.println("response" + jArr);

        for (int i = 0; i < jArr.length(); i++) {
            // create json object
            JSONObject jsonObject = jArr.getJSONObject(i);
            // easy parse fields
            String vid = jsonObject.getString("vid");
            String nid = jsonObject.getString("nid");
            // uid value
            String field_text = jsonObject.getString("field_text");
            String field_edit_ts = jsonObject.getString("field_editts");
            String field_deleted_flag = jsonObject.getString("field_deleted");
            String field_device_name = jsonObject.getString("field_devicename");
            String field_creation_ts = jsonObject.getString("field_creationts");
            String field_device_key = jsonObject.getString("field_devicekey");
         }
    } catch(Exception e){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create class to save state of data you have got and override method equals for compare in your class.

Further, for save data use ArrayList.
For compare used next code.

```
Collection<YourObject> one= new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(obj1, obj2, obj3));
Collection<YourObject> two = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(obj1, obj2, obj3));

one.equals(two)
```

Comment: Could you provide me some example please ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend wrapping both your Database and your JSON data in a `class` and implementing the `equals(Object)` method.

For your JSON data, once you have a class (as above), I'd use GSON (https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to convert directly to Objects

Then for your comparison, convert either your database or JSON data into a `List` (something from `Collections`, or a `HashTable`/`HashMap` (quicker for searching)) and use the `Collections.contains(Object)` (on the `List`) method and a contains count which you compare against the list's size. Here's an example, fill in the blanks:

```
List<YourObject> dbDataList = new ArrayList<YourObject>(Arrays.asList(yourDatabaseDataArray));
int containsCount = 0;
for (YourObject o : yourJsonDataArray){
    if (dbDataList.contains(o))
        containsCount ++;
}
// Success condition is up to you, I'm just comparing the sizes
if (containsCount == dbDataList.size()){
    // Success!
} else {
    // Failure
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

You are creating HasMap which contains two string-variable(key and value). It is possible to search the values with keys for exemple but you cannot sort HashMap. (Array)List could be sorted, as Artyom said.

```
map.put("ID",cc.getString(cc.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.ENTRY_ID)));
```

You are putting string "ID" to the key of every value of the map. Change that to List and sort it with Collections.sort(list,[Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)).